# annoying toast keeps showing how to stop it

Tags: android

Every time I pressed enter the toast keeps popping out even if it should not come out...

take a lot at my code:

```
etAddMove.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getRepeatCount() == 0){
                    String ssmoveName = etAddMove.getText().toString();
                    int x = ssmoveName.length() - 1;
                    if (ssmoveName.isEmpty() || Character.isWhitespace(ssmoveName.charAt(0)) || Character.isWhitespace(ssmoveName.charAt(x))) {
                        Toast.makeText(ListMovingNames.this, 
                                "Please enter a valid name! Avoid giving a blank name or white space at the beginning or end of the name", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        try {
                            SQLHandler check = new SQLHandler(ListMovingNames.this);
                            check.open();
                            String scheck = check.checkMove(ssmoveName);
                            check.close();
                            if (!scheck.equals(ssmoveName)) {
                                Toast.makeText(ListMovingNames.this, "Move name already exist please give a different name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else{
                                SQLHandler entry = new SQLHandler(ListMovingNames.this);
                                entry.open();
                                entry.createMove(ssmoveName);
                                entry.setTodo(ssmoveName);
                                entry.close();
                                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StartMoving.class);
                                i.putExtra("moveName", ssmoveName);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            SQLHandler entry = new SQLHandler(ListMovingNames.this);
                            entry.open();
                            entry.createMove(ssmoveName);
                            entry.setTodo(ssmoveName);
                            entry.close();
                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StartMoving.class);
                            i.putExtra("moveName", ssmoveName);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                return onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
            }
        });
```

how can you make this guy stop if I don't want it to show...

**EDIT**

I think I know why this is happening, It must be because each time i press enter keyup and keydown is initialize thats why the first initialization is keydown which calls the condition and returns false and when keydown is called the condition is called again which will return true, making the toast display. thats what i think so far...

Comment: if (!(ssmoveName.isEmpty() || Character.isWhitespace(ssmoveName.charAt(0)) || Character.isWhitespace(ssmoveName.charAt(x))))
 {
  
 }

Comment: this Toast is the one that keeps comming out
`Toast.makeText(ListMovingNames.this, "Move name already exist please give a different name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` below the  if `(!scheck.equals(ssmoveName))`

Comment: can i come to know why you check if (!scheck.equals(ssmoveName)) ?

Comment: Ops! I forgot to remove the (!) my original code has no ! I was playing with it  thats why i forgot to remove it, removing ! does not fixes the problem, the toast still shows.

Comment: to check the database if that record exist, if it does it will prevent the program from creating an identical one

Comment: I have no problem with it when using buttons, but when checking for the enter key the toast still keeps showing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17536/discussion-between-hardik-joshi-and-philip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solve this shit. As I was suspecting the reason why toast keeps showing is that everytime the enter key is press, the keydown and keyup is called that's why the process is called twice making the toast appear because the condition to show the toast is meet when the process is called the second time.

So to avoid that `KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN` must be present.

```
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if ( (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN  ) && (keyCode== KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)   )
                {               
                    // do something here
                    }
                    return true;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following if not work then come to know.

```
Toast toast;
    toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
if(Yourcondition)
    {
        toast.show();
    }
    else
    {
        //nothing to display
    }
```

Comment: the toast is gone, but my database create a duplicate which I don't want that to happen

Comment: By using this code your database create a duplicate? before this code its working fine?

Comment: yup! when using buttons there's no problem, but when it comes to KeyEvent that's when things start to get ugly

Comment: Sorry dude but I giving you a solution of your question about toast. Dont know how its happen.. And if you solve your toast problem and not foget to accept answer. Thanks :)

Comment: i dont think this code would be responsible for creating a duplicate.! There is definitely something wrong with your other code.

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj i am not getting wht you have advice?

Comment: @hardikjoshi i am just saying your code has no concern with creating a duplicate value. there's definitely something wrong with philip's code.

Comment: @philip can you please mention the code, where you are creating entries in the database.?

Comment: this one doesn't have any connection to the database its just the toast that's keep showing even if the if condition returns false it still shows the toast...

Comment: no sir, toast doesn't appear anymore, the problem with the solution you gave is that even if the statement returns true the toast never appeared where in fact it should

Comment: Did you check if you are getting any exception regarding cursor left open something? I'm not sure, I am still working on your code.

Comment: @Darpan You also fatch this problem in your project?

Comment: not same, but we got a repetitive problem due to code written in catch block, when we failed to notice there was an exception unnoticed.

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
   Toast toast;
        toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    if(Yourcondition)
        {
            toast.show();
        }
        else
        {
            //nothing to display
        }
```

In the last answer, you are using `.show` method, when you are creating the toast. It will show the even, if the statement is true or not.
So, remove `.show` from

```
toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

this statement.

This might help.